# JAXB unmarshalling provides null

Tags: java, jaxb

I know there are many question like mine. But I don't know how to solve my problem.
That's my classes.

I have such App class as Main class. Also I have such xml data. I need to parse it to get list of Saccreq objects.

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String data = "<MT94x>&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;979373531_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;BEGIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1089699343_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1090788724_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;7&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1090858234_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;REFUSE&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1167198643_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN1&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1092582159_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1093640470_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1094544929_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;5&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1097041457_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1097685077_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1098520777_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;11&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1101668069_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1102311654_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1103381880_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1103707818_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;1&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1104481517_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;6&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1109203484_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;&lt;saccreq&gt;&lt;id&gt;1117235778_410&lt;/id&gt;&lt;code&gt;9&lt;/code&gt;&lt;state&gt;FIN&lt;/state&gt;&lt;/saccreq&gt;</MT94x>";
        MT94x result = stringToObject(data, MT94x.class);
        System.out.println(result.getSaccreq());
    }

    public static <T> T stringToObject(final String textClazz, final Class<T> clazz){
        T returnedValue;
        try {
            final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(clazz);
            final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
            final StringReader reader = new StringReader(textClazz);
            returnedValue = (T) unmarshaller.unmarshal(reader);
        } catch ( final JAXBException e ) {
            throw new RuntimeException("an error occurred while unmarshalling xml into " + clazz.getCanonicalName() + " object", e );
        }
        return returnedValue;
    }

}
```

Unmarshalling provides null value for Saccreq list. I just get "[]" in result.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

@XmlRootElement(name = "MT94x")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MT94x implements Serializable {

    public MT94x(){}

    @XmlElement(name = "saccreq")
    private List<Saccreq> saccreq;

    public List<Saccreq> getSaccreq(){
        if (saccreq == null){
            saccreq = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        return this.saccreq;
    }

    public void setSaccreq(List<Saccreq> saccreqs){
        this.saccreq = saccreqs;
    }
}
```

As you see in Saccreq class I have 3 field elements which values are in "data" variable in App class.

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Saccreq {

    @XmlElement
    private String id;
    @XmlElement
    private String code;
    @XmlElement
    private String state;

    public Saccreq(){}

    public void setId(String id){
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setCode(String code){
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setState(String state){
        this.state = state;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return state;
    }
}
```

Can somebody give good advice to solve this?

Comment: Can you put the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @hlfernandez
[]
no exception, just this answer empty value.

Comment: Alright. Then my first try would be removing the `if (saccreq == null){saccreq = new ArrayList<>();}` part from the `getSaccreq` method. See what happens and if you need it, put it in the constructor.

Comment: @hlfernandez i just get null instead of []

Comment: Have you tried unmarshalling a single `Saccreq` object? If not, try it to ensure that unmarshalling works for the base clase.

Comment: `StringEscapeUtils.unescapeXml(data);` solved my issue

Comment: @hlfernandez how to close the issue?

Comment: I think you have an option to close your question just below the initial post. If not, you can add a new answer with the solution so that others can see it and close the thread.